# How should choose the suitable phy layer for bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

I am going to propose some solutions related to the IP for Bluetooth. I am proposing my solutions in layers of Host.

1. My problem is that how can i select the best phy for my solution? in my approach, I need to have long rage, low power and big packet transmission.
2. What are the main features offered with phy? what I know is that phy can impact on range, throughput, power. Is it all or is there anything else that I didn't recognize?
3. My devices are small and working with coin batteries. I do not have audio transmission. should I go with EDR PHY, BR PHY, LE 2M PHY, LE 1M PHY or LE Coded PHY?
4. Is it possible to use different PHY based on BL link quality to achieve specific application requirements? there is a paper entitled " Performance and Trade-offs of the new PHY Modes of BLE 5" showing that how to select the best phy based on the BL link quality.
5. has the phy impact on the following? if so, what feature of the phy should be considered?

   a) Supported Packets Per Connection Event

   b) Maximum Supported ATT MTU Size

   c) Maximum Supported Link Layer Data Packet Size

Comment: "long rage, low power and big packet transmission." So you're willing to give up data rate, right? That sounds like exactly the use of code of LE Coded. LE Coded increases the error-correction overhead, giving excellent range and power, while reducing the room available for data. You mentioned iOS in your tags, but you don't mention it anywhere in your question. For longer range solutions where you control all the hardware, you should also be looking at LoRa, since that's its whole goal. It depends a bit on what you mean by "long range." 10s of meters? 1000s of meters? Different problems.

Comment: Since you've tagged iOS, what is your minimum iPhone platform? Pre-8 devices don't support Bluetooth 5, so your options are different. And what are your OS requirements? GATT over BR/EDR isn't available on iOS before around 13 (did you really mean to tag GATT here?) Do you only need to work with iPhones? No Android or other devices? (Or is this related to iOS at all?)

Comment: @ Rob Napier i have removed ios tag. it was a mistake sorry. u mentioned something that " LE Coded  ... while reducing the room available for data." I was thinking that the max PDU size for all of  LE 2M PHY, LE 1M PHY orLE Coded PHY are 257. Isn't it? in my approach i don't want to use LoRa and the goal is using BL. By long range i mean  one or two kilometers (as much as possible). I will use a Linux based operating system.  So for using GATT i need to take care about the OS yes?

Comment: At those ranges and low power, you need more error correction in the protocol for BLE to work, so you lose data rate. Do you still mean to list core-bluetooth here? (That tag relates to an iOS library). 1-2km is pushing the envelope of what you can do with BLE. You'll want directional antennas on both sides, a fairly clear line of sight, and all the power you can put into them. And you'll definitely want LE Coded. The Bluetooth site includes a calculator, but these are best case. https://www.bluetooth.com/learn-about-bluetooth/key-attributes/range/#estimator

Comment: BTW, I'm very doubtful you can do this with coin batteries over these kinds of ranges with BLE. You're going to need too much power to do this with Bluetooth IMO.

Comment: I'm also now really curious about running Linux on coin batteries. Can you really get Linux that power efficient? I've seen it in plenty of embedded systems, but always in things you regularly recharged. How much battery life are you seeing?

Comment: The site and the Bluetooth Range Estimator you mentioned in your comment are indeed useful for me.   Oh, does it mean that for the LE 1M Coded PHY with s=8, the max PDU is 64 bytes?

Comment: No. The PDU is the same size, the packets are just longer. Packets can now be up to 17ms. But particular systems may negotiate that down of course. That's a lot of heat and I expect a lot of chips may not be able to handle it (especially if you *also* plan to turn up  the transmit power). See page 222 of the 5.2 Core Spec, Table 3.3 for details. https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/core-specification/

Comment: (I'm totally speculating about the heat problems. 17ms just seems like a very large jump in continuous power, and Bluetooth is, after all, just a tiny, unshielded microwave oven right beside all the electronics… :D) Speaking of which, one thing I haven't heard anyone talk about is the impact of rain or fog on these long-range BLE signals. Water eats microwaves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we talk about BLE, the three different PHYs are quite similar from the radio point of view. What you need to know is that they all usually consume basically the same current (not energy) while the radio is on (with some small differences). The difference is that the radio needs to be on for longer times with shorter bitrates (and hence consume more energy in total) and shorter times with higher bitrates. Higher bitrates lead to worse delivery success rate than lower bitrates. So everything is just a tradeoff between range, speed and energy usage.

Note that a BLE radio can typically only do one radio operation at a time, so with the LE packet length extension, a maximum length Coded PHY packet can take 17 ms, which might reduce the ability for the firmware to schedule other activities, such as scanning or handle another connection. On the Link Layer, the two endpoints can negotiate the maximum time and maximum packet size, so yes, you can end up in a situation where the maximum packet length depends on the PHY used (but the link layer will segment it so it won't be any issues for the host side). You can also realise that with 2M PHY you can fit much more packets compared with other PHYs during a certain amount of time, for example one connection event with a firmware-decided deadline when it must end.

Also keep in mind that to establish a connection using Coded PHY, you need to use the new "extended advertisements", which are not backwards-compatible with devices not supporting Coded PHY, or devices that support Coded PHY but are not set up to scan using Coded PHY.

When a connection is established, you can change PHY at any time. For example if you monitor the RSSI and detect a change in signal quality you can change the PHY.

The ATT MTU is decided by the host layer and is completely separate from the link layer. Although, of course a programmer could for some reason decide to use shorter MTUs when Coded PHY is used, but I haven't heard about anyone doing so.

Don't forget that you can also change the TX power of your radio to increase the range (and current consumption) your sent packets will reach. You can also select a chip with better RX sensitivity to get better range when receiving packets. Or use an antenna amplifier.